# How do I run/trigger service in startup.cs?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a service which grabs the token and save in cache, I added service like below, but it's not running when the app starts what do I need to do to trigger this service on startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
   services.AddScoped<ITokenService,TokenService>();
}
```

Comment: If this is a service that needs to be run in the background consider making it a [Hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: The frame work will start it up as part of the startup process. Which is what I think you were looking to do.

Comment: Yeah and also I need to trigger it after every 50 min and doc says in runs on a timer so its perfect I guess

Comment: What you can do is create a hosted service, inject your token service as it is now, and call the desired functions when needed from within the hosted service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a service that needs to be run in the background consider using it with a Hosted service

Reference [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)

> I need to trigger it after every 50 min

What you can do is create a hosted service, inject your token service as it is now, and call the desired functions when needed from within the hosted service.

The frame work will start the hosted service as part of the startup process.

Answer (score 7):

Calling `services.AddScoped` just adds it to the service collection. Nothing happens as a result of that, i.e. it's not going to just automatically new up an instance and run some method on it.

If you need something to happen once at startup, you need to actually do that in `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    var tokenService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>();
    tokenService.DoSomething();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: I think the question was an XY problem. Looks like the OP needed a Hosted Service with a timed background task.

Comment: @Chris what if I need to run this service on startup as well as after every 50 min?

Comment: Yep. That would be a situation where you need a hosted service.